# Creating a link on a website to POST to "ifttt.com" but stay on my site

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to create a link on a website that uses an IFTTT link to turn a switch on/off.

I can control the switch directly using cURL in a terminal or Python's requests library (see below).  If I add the IFTTT link directly to my website, the user is directed away from my site when they click the link.

I have no clue on how to make this work on the website, as my knowledge of JavaScript is limited to say the least.

Code I am using in terminal:

```
curl -X POST http://maker.ifttt.com/etc/etc
```

In Python:

```
def send_event():
    requests.post("http://maker.ifttt.com/etc/etc")
```

Comment: Did you try with an ajax?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for the question.  Because you're a new user, your question came up for review.  I think it is very unlikely that someone would give you an answer that would involve using either Python or cURL, so I removed those tags and also modified the title.  I also adjusted the phrasing of the question and reformatted some of the code.  If you disagree with the changes, you can edit your question further.

Answer (score 0):

You could make that with an ajax. If for example, using [jQuery's ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you could do:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://maker.ifttt.com/etc/etc",
    method: "POST"
});
```

This wont make any redirects to the user, you should also check the success status to show a message or something.

I recommend you read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: I'd be surprised if you can get away with this, XSS protection should block it.

Comment: @SeanMcSomething why? It can be allowed by the server

Comment: @PabloMatiasGomez Meant to say CSRF.  Could the server allow it?  Sure but I doubt the server is set up to accept arbitrary AJAX requests from random webpages without you jumping through some more complicated hoops.

Answer (score 0):

If your web service supports for `GET`requests, you can do it with plain javascript as follows. Paste below code in developer console after adding your correct service URL. If your web service haven't configured for [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), you can't use ajax. Otherwise ajax POST is nice to use.

```
(
    function (a,b,c,d) {
      b.type= c;
      b.src= d;
      a.appendChild(b);
})
 (
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0], 
    document.createElement('script'), 
    'text/javascript', 
    'http://maker.ifttt.com/etc/etc'
 );
```